# Randomly order data with weights

Tags: r, random

I have some data `x = 1:10` and weights `w = 1:10`. I want to generate a randomly re-ordered version of `x` (all 10 elements), where the **order** is weighted by `w`. For example, the `x[10]` should have 10-times the probability of appearing first vs `x[1]`.

One approach is to sample elements one-at-a-time, each time with weights `w` (adjusted for non-replacement), but obviously this is slow.
Another approach could use the integer weights (special case) as follows:

```
x[order(match(x,sample(rep(x,w))))]
```

but this scales badly in memory. FWIW this implementation replicates each `x[i]` `w[i]` times, then shuffles this randomly. Then, finds the first occurrence of each `x[i]` in the replicated data and uses this to define the final order.

**Question**: How can I efficiently, randomly order `x` with (non-integer) weights `w`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the `sample` function, with `replace=FALSE`, `size=length(x)` (default), and `prob=w` as the weights, seems to naturally order the result by weights `w`, presumably due to some internal procedure like the first case described above, which is still implemented in a fast way.

So, it's as simple as: `sample(x,prob=w)`

As a simple illustration, we can plot the mean values over a large number (`1e4`) of repetitions:

```
set.seed(0)
X = sapply(1:1e4,function(z){ sample(x,prob=w) })
plot(rowMeans(X))
```

which is monotonic (although not linear) decreasing, as expected. Aside: *It's not linear because a `w = 9` vs `w = 10` has less influence compared to `w = 1` vs `w = 2`. To get the linear result we can use weights `a^w` for any exponent base `a`.*